# Concatenate a variable with a string

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

I wrote a small bat file:

```
@echo off

rem runs the {arg[0].exe} - using its fully qualified name
%~f1

IF %errorlevel% NEQ 0 
(set boolResult=False) 
ELSE 
(set boolResult=True) 


rem case1 
EVENTCREATE /T ERROR /ID 700 /L "MyTest Application" /D "exitcode: %errorlevel%; session id is %SessionName%"

rem case3
EVENTCREATE /T ERROR /ID 700 /L APPLICATION /D "exitcode: %boolResult%; session id is %SessionName%"

rem case4 
EVENTCREATE /T ERROR /ID 700 /L APPLICATION /D "exitcode: %errorlevel%; session id is %SessionName%"
```

And I have got some questions, if you could help me out...

1. case1: I get the following error:

   ERROR: 'MyTest Application' log does not exist. Cannot create the event.

*The only way to initial eventlog in through high-leve (c#) code?

2. case3: How can I concatenate a string with some bat variable ?
3. case4: How do I add a newline in the description?

"exitcode: %boolResult%\n session id is %SessionName%"

didn't do that.

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

> *The only way to initial eventlog in through high-leve (c#) code?*

This is correct, there is no command line tool to create new event logs. One option here would be to use a PowerShell script and use the [System.Diagnostics.Eventlog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx) class.

---

> *case3: How can I concatenate a string
>   with some bat variable ?*

The way you do is right, so your log entry text

```
EVENTCREATE /T ERROR /ID 700 /L "MyTest Application" /D "exitcode: %errorlevel%; session id is %SessionName%"
```

should expand to:

```
EVENTCREATE /T ERROR /ID 700 /L "MyTest Application" /D "exitcode: 0; session id is Console"
```

---

> *case4: How do I add a newline in the
>   description?*

You can't. There is no way of providing a newline via command line parameters.

Comment: As for PowerShell, there are cmdlets for dealing with Windows event logs, both legacy and current ones. No need to use the .NET classes.

Comment: @Johannes: Thanks for the mentioning. I'm not very fimilar with PowerShell yet. And you are right, environment variables are not case-sensitive.
Don't know why I have thought so up to now.